# How to reference variable in xsl:text element?

Tags: xslt

I have a stylesheet where I would prefer to insert predefined string variable in xsl text element, but can't find any pointers while searching the web.

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="node()/ref/text()"/>
...
<xsl:text>Some text where I want to append $var variable desperately</xsl:text>
...
```

I tried with $var, ($var), {$var}...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Some text where I want to include the value of <xsl:value-of select='$var'/>.
```

Note that `<xsl:text>` is only needed to control the behavior on whitespace. Most of the time, you can simply type text and just include this element when the result is not what you expected – I guess knowing the rules for when to use `<xsl:text>` doesn't hurt, however. :) (And it's not complicated: Use `<xsl:text>` if otherwise, your text nodes would only have white space or if they would include additional whitespace you want to avoid at either end.)

EDIT: Note that whitespace in variables doesn't need `xsl:text` for protection when used, that is only for the XSL parsing step:

```
<xsl:variable name="newline"><!-- can be global -->
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:when test="starts-with(., $newline)">
  ...
</xsl:when>

Here's some text<xsl:value-of select='$newline' />with formatting.
```

Comment: Yes I use it for white space (LF) and actually variable I wanted to insert is also predefined formating space :D So workaround can be made with `<xsl:value ...>` but not inside `<xsl:text>` element as it's not allowed. I'll wait to see if it's indeed not possible by other means, and then I'll marked your answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @theta: are you saying that `<xsl:value-of>` is not allowed inside a `<xsl:text>` element? Wow you're right. I had forgotten.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
    'Some text where I want to append ', 
    $var, 
    ' variable desperately')" />
```

Although it's a bit ugly, this gives you full control of the white space between your text and the variable's text.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 7):

`xsl:text` is only used to output fixed text, and it cannot contain nested instructions. The instruction to output variable text is `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Update 9 years later: in XSLT 3.0 you can write `<xsl:text>Some text where I want to append {$var}</xsl:text>` provided the `expand-text` option is set.

Comment: FWIW, using moustache syntax, or allowing for user-defined sigils alongside `expand-text`, would have permitted `public class {{className}} extends Alarm {`; whereas `public class {$className} ... {` doesn't work, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this to create a variable with string and another variable on it

```
<xsl:variable name="imgsrc">http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/buttons/<xsl:value-of select='$iconSize' />/<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($licenceTypeAndText, '|')" /></xsl:variable>
```

and this will produce a variable with a value like this

```
http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/buttons/80x15/png/by.png
```